# Tomcat deployement issue in a Maven project

Tags: maven, tomcat, maven-3, pom.xml

I have been trying to create a simple maven web based project to be confident about maven. I have added tomcat7 plugin in my pom.xml to use it as a server. But when i started to deploy my war file to tomcat by using

> tomcat7:deploy

it is throwing an error as follows,

```
[INFO] Deploying war to http://127.0.0.1:8080/MavenWeb  
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 13.585s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jan 30 16:03:06 IST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/24M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.0:deploy  (default-cli) on project MavenWeb: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Connection to http://127.0.0.1:8080 refused: Connection refused -> [Help 1]
```

My plugin section in pom.xml is as follows.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <configuration>
       <url>http://127.0.0.1:8080/manager/html</url>
       <warFile>/home/shebin/Maven Folder/MavenWeb/target/MavenWeb.war</warFile>
   <server>TomcatServer</server>
       <path>/MavenWeb</path>
   <username>tomcat</username>
       <password>tomcat</password>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

.m2/settings.xml and /home/shebin/apache-maven-3.0.4/conf/settings.xml

```
<server>
        <id>TomcatServer</id>
        <username>tomcat</username>
        <password>tomcat</password>
</server>
```

/home/shebin/apache-tomcat-7.0.35/conf/tomcat-users.xml

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="manager-gui"/>
```

I have came through various solution and nothing is working in my way. My Maven version is 3.0.4 and using tomcat7 plugin.

Comment: Did you first verify that you can deploy a WAR file directly in the tomcat manager web interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.0:deploy  (default-cli) on project MavenWeb: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Connection to http://127.0.0.1:8080 refused: Connection refused -> [Help 1]
```

insinuates this is authentication related. Try and change this

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="manager-gui"/>
```

to

```
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="manager-script"/>
```

Access from the maven plugin will not happen over the browser based admin client :)

Comment: Its too not working. still the same error.
Also what you mean by "Access from the maven plugin will not happen over the browser based admin client"..

Comment: the role you specified "mananger-gui" gives users who have that role access to the HTML based admin gui. All I meant is that the maven plug-in wont be deploying the war though the gui, so it is the wrong role to use. Try the role manager-script instead :)

Answer (score 3):

The url in configuration of maven plugin should be `<url>http://127.0.0.1:8080/manager/text</url>` which corresponds to the role `manager-script`.

Also, it is worth noted that after changing the `roles` in `{TOMCAT_HOME}/conf/tomcat-users.xml`, you have to restart the tomcat server for reloading the configuration. I know this is a common sense, but my experience told me that some of you may really stuck at here.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue. You'll need to add an extra role to the mix: manager-jmx. So your tomcat-users.xml file should have.

```
<user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="manager-script, manager-jmx"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I got this working too thanks to points in this post.. Things I got stuck on were:
The POM file - you need a slash on the beginning of the path (or it tried to install it under /manager/ and fails):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <url>http://10.54.17.35:8080/manager/text</url>
        <server>LoginForTomcat</server>
        <path>/displayService</path>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

provide server credentials in ~/.m2/settings.xml:

```
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>LoginForTomcat</id>
        <username>figgy</username>
        <password>passw0rd</password>
    </server>
</servers>
```

On the tomcat server, you need to define manager-script and manager-jmx:

```
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-script"/>
  <role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
  <user username="figgy" password="passw0rd" roles="manager-gui,manager-script,manager-jmx"/>
```

Looking over this everything here is in the posts above, posting this to clarify things.