# Tomcat 7 maven plugin - I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Broken pipe

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I read all the questions regarding my issue with no success...
I'm depolying my war with maven and I want it to go to tomcat server on another ip.

I followed all the settings...

My POM for the plugin

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <url>http://192.168.3.67:8080/manager/text</url>
            <server>TomcatServer</server>
            <path>webapp</path>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

My /conf/settings.xml for tomcat has

```
<server>
        <id>TomcatServer</id>
        <username>maven</username>
        <password>maven</password>
</server>
```

And tomcat-user.xml is as follows

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<user username="system" password="raspberry" roles="manager-gui"/>
<user username="maven" password="maven" roles="manager-script"/>
```

When I try to deploy the application I got

```
[INFO] Deploying war to http://192.168.3.67:8080/manager/webapp  
Uploading: http://192.168.3.67:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=webapp
2472/14845 KB   
[INFO] I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Broken pipe
[INFO] Retrying request
Uploading: http://192.168.3.67:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=webapp
2384/14845 KB   
[INFO] I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Broken pipe
[INFO] Retrying request
Uploading: http://192.168.3.67:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=webapp
2398/14845 KB   
[INFO] I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Broken pipe
[INFO] Retrying request
Uploading: http://192.168.3.67:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=webapp
2472/14845 KB   
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.867 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-11-25T14:58:05+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/228M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:deploy (default-cli) on project webapp: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Broken pipe -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:deploy (default-cli) on project webapp: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.AbstractCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractCatalinaMojo.java:141)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.AbstractWarCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractWarCatalinaMojo.java:68)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:113)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:159)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.write(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:181)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthOutputStream.write(ContentLengthOutputStream.java:115)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.common.deployer.TomcatManager$RequestEntityImplementation.writeTo(TomcatManager.java:880)
    at org.apache.http.entity.HttpEntityWrapper.writeTo(HttpEntityWrapper.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper$EntityWrapper.writeTo(EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.entity.EntitySerializer.serialize(EntitySerializer.java:117)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:265)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.sendRequestEntity(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:203)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:121)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:682)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:486)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.common.deployer.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:742)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.common.deployer.TomcatManager.deployImpl(TomcatManager.java:705)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.common.deployer.TomcatManager.deploy(TomcatManager.java:388)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.deploy.AbstractDeployWarMojo.deployWar(AbstractDeployWarMojo.java:85)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.invokeManager(AbstractDeployMojo.java:82)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.AbstractCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractCatalinaMojo.java:132)
    ... 23 more
```

I can simply deploy the application going to the manager page of the server, the server is reachable... I can't understand what can be...

Comment: Looks like a firewall/network issue. Are you able to upload the file from your browser?

Comment: I have no firewall at all... I'm in an internal LAN with the server. I can send files via FTP or SSH, and I can deploy them by uploading the war from the /manager page of tomcat... Just the plugin seems not to work...

Comment: Just for the sake of having tried it: what happens when you try to use version 2.3-SNAPSHOT of the plugin which seems to be the last they made for Tomcat 7? Broken pipe is rather non-specific, but you can be pretty sure it is because the host (the Tomcat 7 server) prematurely closes the connection for whatever reason. On that note, perhaps there is something in the logs of the Tomcat 7 server?

Comment: Nothing to do @Gimby i changed the version but i have the some problem. Nothing is written in the apache logs except the tries to load the war - 25-Nov-2015 16:19:39.843 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Manager: deploy: Deploying web application 'webapp'

Comment: Not exactly the same, but still worth a read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14602744/tomcat-deployement-issue-in-a-maven-project

Comment: Basically any of the many existing questions seem to boil down to missing roles: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25336099/error-when-i-try-deploy-application-to-tomcat7-server

Comment: Thank you Gimby, I read those questions, my war is 13mb and I have the manager-script role in my settings.xml...

Comment: I want just to add that I've moved tomcat in the same machine I have my workspace, so with Maven I have to deploy on the some machine... but i get the same error...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the path should start with slash.

change

`<path>webapp</path>`

to

`<path>/webapp</path>`

Answer (score 6):

I have the same problem, and solved now.
Just read this [Tomcat deployement issue in a Maven project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14602744/tomcat-deployement-issue-in-a-maven-project), by Belden Schroeder.

Ensure all of the following manager roles are added to your tomcat-users.xml.

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
<role rolename="manager-status"/>
<user username="test1" password="test" roles="manager-script,manager-jmx" />
```

run: `mvn tomcat7:deploy`

output :

```
[INFO] --- tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:deploy (default-cli) @ xx ---
[INFO] Deploying war to http://localhost:8080/xx  
Uploading: http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=%2Fxx
Uploaded: http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=%2Fxx (4801 KB at 25809.4 KB/sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the tomcat port or path in the local configuration file is consistent with the remote tomcat